# SQL and/or LINQ query for determining daily increases in viewers

Tags: c#, sql, linq

We're montioring usage of a certain resources by monitoring users logins (We can see user logins growing daily). After filtering out repeat inter day logins for users, we'd like to track the # of  users using the service each day, and then using that info to determine overall incremental gains for each calendar day. Our table is pretty simple:

```
class ServiceLogin 
{
    String login;
    DateTime loginTime;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do what you want. It groups all visitors by the date of the login and then count how many unique logins there were in the day.

```
var visitorsPerDay = from l in Logins
                     group l.login by l.loginTime.Date into g
                     select new { Day = g.Key, Logins = g.Distinct().Count();
```